# Connecting laravel to postgres db

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I am working on a project where I need to connect Laravel to a postgres db.  First time doing this, in the past just used mysql. I am getting this error  `PDOException::("SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host` when I try to run `php artisan migrate`.  I am on a mac so I used `brew install postgresql`.  This is a db that already has tables in it.

In my .env file I changed my db to

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=<host name>
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=<db name>
DB_USERNAME=<user name>
DB_PASSWORD=<password>
```

What else am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your config is missing in `pg_hba.conf` file.

Suppose you are on localhost, have you tried adding `host  all  all 0.0.0.0/0 md5` entry in your `pg_hba.conf`? Remember to restart your postgresql services after that.